# Meteor session keeps resetting in cart

Tags: session, meteor

I am building a web store using Meteor. I am having an issue where a Meteor session gets reset when an item is added to cart. A user can add an item to cart from two locations - a master products listing page and a product detail page.

Scenario A: A customer is on the master products listing page and adds an item to cart. The customer then clicks on a products detail page for another item. The customer then adds an item to the cart from the products detail page. A new session is created and the items that were added on the products listing page disappear and only the products from the product detail page are in the cart.

So my problem is that a new session is created when an item is added to cart and I'm not sure why that's happening...

Here is the addToCart click event from my productDetails.js:

```
'click .add-to-cart': function (e, tmpl) {
e.preventDefault();

var quantity = $('[name=qty]').val();
var thisProduct = Products.findOne();
var sessionId = Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId;
var productInfo = {
  productCode: thisProduct.productCode,
  memPrice: thisProduct.memPrice,
  brand: thisProduct.brand,
  size: thisProduct.size,
  description: thisProduct.description,
  quantity: quantity,
  sessionId: sessionId
};
Session.set('sessionId', sessionId);

console.log(productInfo);

if (quantity > 0) {
  Meteor.call('addToCart', quantity, productInfo);
  Router.go('Tires');
} else {
  alert('Please input a desired quantity');
}
```

}

Here is my addToCart click event from my master products page:

```
'click .add-to-cart': function (e, tmpl) {
e.preventDefault();

var currUser = Meteor.user();   
if(!currUser) {
  alert("Please register for an account before you may add items to cart");
} else if (!currUser.profile.confirmed) {
  alert("Your account needs to be confirmed before you may add items to cart. Please contact info@info.org for assistance.")
} else {
  var currentRow = $(e.target).closest('tr');
  var quantity = currentRow.find('.item-quantity').val();
  var sessionId = Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId;
  var productInfo = {
    productCode: this.productCode,
    memPrice: this.memberPrice,
    brand: this.brand,
    size: this.size,
    description: this.description,
    quantity: quantity,
    sessionId: sessionId
  };
  Session.set('sessionId', sessionId);

  if (quantity > 0) {
    Meteor.call('addToCart', quantity, productInfo);
    currentRow.find('.item-quantity').val(0);
  } else {
    alert('Please input a desired quantity');
  }
};
```

}

And here is my addToCart method:

```
addToCart: function(qty, productInfo, cb) {
    console.log('//-------------Item Data-------------');
    console.log("Product Info: ", productInfo);

    if (qty > 0) {
        Cart.insert(productInfo);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` gives you the websocket "session" id, it is not persistent nor a way to keep track of the user session like a cookie. 
You should rely on user accounts and store the cart in the profile, or use another Mongo collection.